# Update employee ID from temp table only if employee exists in both tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have a table in a database called **T_USR** which includes the following fields:-

```
USRUID (Primary Key)
USRID <- This is the current employee ID
```

I also have a temp table **#TEMP3** populated from a CSV file which includes:

```
USRUID (the value of this field will match the Primary Key in T_USR)
EMPID <- This is to be the new employee ID
```

#TEMP3 contains only a subset of the users found in T_USR

What i need is a query that will update the value of T_USR.USRID with the value from #TEMP3.EMPID ONLY if the member of staff (USRUID) exists in both tables.

This is the query I wrote, but for users who appear in T_USR and *NOT* in #TEMP3, the USRID field was set to NULL which is not the required result. For users who do not appear in both tables, I want their details to remain unchanged.

```
Update dbo.T_USR
SET dbo.T_USR.USRID = 
(SELECT dbo.#TEMP3.EMPID
FROM #TEMP3
Where dbo.T_USR.USRUID = dbo.#TEMP3.USRUID
and exists (
select * from #TEMP3 where dbo.T_USR.USRUID = #TEMP3.USRUID)
)
```

I'd appreciate any suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: Consumable sample data (as DDL and DML statements) and expected results will help us help you here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this :

```
UPDATE t
SET USRID = EMPID
 FROM #TEMP3 te
JOIN dbo.T_USR t ON t.USRUID = te.USRUID
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `join`.  If I understand correctly:

```
update u
    set u.usrid = t.empid
    from dbo.T_USR u join
         #temp3 t
         on u.usruid = t.usruid
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Following Query, it Will update only rows exists on both table.

```
Update dbo.T_USR
SET dbo.T_USR.USRID = 
(SELECT dbo.#TEMP3.EMPID
FROM #TEMP3
Where dbo.T_USR.USRUID = dbo.#TEMP3.USRUID
)
WHERE  exists (
select * from #TEMP3 AS TT where dbo.T_USR.USRUID = TT.USRUID)
```